# Can I change tab width (\t) in a PHP string?

Tags: php

I'm not even sure if its possible, but I'd like to change the value of \t in PHP strings. For example, currently if I do this:

```
echo "\t\tHello";
```

The output is 16 spaces followed by hello - so the tab width is 8 spaces. Is there a way to change this default tab width to another number when using \t in strings?

Its not really all that important that I do so, and there are numerous, obvious work arounds, just wondering if I'm missing out on something easy to do and can't find.

Comment: Yeah, you're missing something. PHP do not render.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The tab width is not specified by PHP, but by the program which views it. If you view it in an editor, you can set the tab width in the editor.

Comment: My editor must save tabs as spaces then. When I create a HTML file I use tabs (4 spaces) and it displays them as 4 spaces; but when I generate HTML via PHP with the \t character, the source in the browser shows those tabs as 8, and the ones from my editor as 4. I should have known this. I blame it on being 6AM.

Comment: It can vary from editor to editor. My editor of choice (TextPad) allows me to define tabstops based on file extension, so I can set 8 for HTML and 4 for PHP if I wish), and also offers an option to convert tabs to spaces on save.

Comment: @Will if your editor do replace a tab with 4 spaces, your PHP script should just do the same.