# Change indentation space for PHPs "\t"

Tags: php, tabs, indentation, output

Is it possible to change the indentation space for "\t" in PHP? Searched for a while now but can't find anything pointing to an answer. I know there are some libraries out there that can tidy up the output but I'd prefer to be able to set this anyway, and to keep it consistant with my HTML indentation. I wish to change this indentation so that it becomes 4 spaces instead of the default "tab" if possible.

Comment: PHP doesn't do anything with indentation, that's an editor thing. To PHP spaces and tabs and newlines are all just whitespace.

Comment: Hm ok, but shouldn't it be possible to set the amount of space that each "\t" would provide? I assume it will be different from each platform it runs on but still.

Comment: Thanks everyone for clarifying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want tabs from a text input to become 4 spaces you can do this:

```
$formatted_string = preg_replace("/\t/", "    ", $string);
```

For this to work on a html page you might want to replace the spaces with four `&nbsp;`

Comment: `\s` doesn't mean anything in the replacement string.

Comment: I changed to 4 spaces to make sure, but thought you could use \s if you used double quotes. Guess that only applies to `\r`, `\n`, `\t`

Answer (score 4):

« The tab width is not specified by PHP, but by the program which views it. If you view it in an editor, you can set the tab width in the editor. »

[Can I change tab width (\t) in a PHP string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829896/can-i-change-tab-width-t-in-a-php-string)

[Specifying Tab-Width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667200/specifying-tab-width)

Answer (score 1):

A tab character is a tab character. It doesn't have a width, it's a tab character. The thing (editor, viewer, browser) that is rendering the tab character visually (by indenting content) decides the width. There's no PHP or other "setting".